# Google+ sign in onConnected not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-plus

I am writing a log in fragment that hosts Facebook and Google+ sign in. The fragment is a parent fragment for three fragments with user content that are called with view pager after successful log in. I am storing email and service name in shared preferences upon retrieval from Google or Facebook, and then if successful the view pager is displayed with user fragments. Facebook log in works fine but when I start Google+ sign in it does not get to the onConnected callback method. When I switch to other tabs and return to log in fragment it is somehow triggered and I get user fragments. How can i trigger the onConnected method upon pressing the Google+ sign in button?

to ensure the onActivityResult is called i added this in main activity

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
     LoginFragment lf = (LoginFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Login");
    if (lf != null) {
        lf.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

}
```

LoginFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Session class instance
    mSession = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    setupGoogleplus();
    loginButton = (SignInButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                    mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                } else {
                    try {
                        mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        // Try connecting again.
                        mConnectionResult = null;
                        mPlusClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    setupViewPager();

    if (mSession.isLoggedIn()) {
        onLoged();
    }

}


private void setupViewPager() {
    mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);

}

private void setupGoogleplus() {
    // google+ part
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(getSherlockActivity(), new ConnectionCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
            // new
            // DownloadImageTask(userPicture).execute(mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson().getImage().getUrl());
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), accountName + " is connected.",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mSession.createLoginSession(mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson().getName().getGivenName().toString(), mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "Google+");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
        }
    }, new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to
                // resolve
                // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss
                // the
                // connection dialog.
                if (result.hasResolution()) {
                    try {
                        result.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        mPlusClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a
            // user click.
            mConnectionResult = result;
        }
    }).setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        // Request user data and show the results
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (user != null) {
                    // Display the parsed user info
                    // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                    // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                    // profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                    // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
                    mSession.createLoginSession(user.getName(), user.getProperty("email").toString(), "Facebook");
                    onLoged();
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient.connect();
    } else {
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
}

private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new FirstFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SecondFragment();
        case 2:
            return new ThirdFragment();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "1";
        case 1:
            return "2";
        case 2:
            return "3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    mPlusClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}

public void googleLogout() {

    if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
        mPlusClient.connect();
        mSession.logoutUser();
    }
}

public void onLoged() {

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    authButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

public void onNotLoged() {

    mViewPager.setAdapter(null);
    mViewPager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    authButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}}
```

In onConnected method I call mySession object creation (shared preferences) to store the data and onLoged to display user fragments. Why do I have to switch tabs a few times for onConnected to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the resolution for the connection failure was started with startIntentSenderForResult and the code REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR, you need to capture the result inside Activity.onActivityResult.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}
```

So in your case you should call `mPlusClient.connect();` in LoginFragment onActivityResult after all needed checks.